# How can I collide a trigger and a non - trigger in unity 2D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, triggers, 2d

is there a way which I can collide a trigger collider and a non-trigger collider? I tried using different rigidbody types but it didn't really work.
As you can see one of them has istrigger turned to true, the other one to false.
Here's my colliders :
[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Unity Collision Action Matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html), **OnTrigger** messages will be sent in case of a **Kinematic Rigidbody Trigger** collides with a **Kinematic Rigidbody Collider**: [Trigger message matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvMfF.png)

However, **OnCollision** messages will **not** be called in this instance:
[Collision message matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x63al.png)

i.e. `OnTrigger Enter2D/Exit2D/Stay2D` will be called, while `OnCollision Enter2D/Exit2D/Stay2D` will not. Also note that since your colliders are all 2D, you need to use the "2D" suffix on the collision functions.